# Placing text inside a tikz-timing table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

I am new to the `tikz-timing` package and `tikz` in general. I am having trouble adding some text under my signals like in the example down below. Basically i want to add zeros under the L and ones under the H singals. I tried adding them as text under the singals like you would in a table but that doesn't work.
I appreciate your help!

```
    \begin{tikztimingtable}
        Node 1 & LHHLHHHLHLHL        \\
               & 011011101010        \\
        Node 2 & LHHLHHHH4D{Empfang} \\
               & 01101111            \\
        Bus    & LHHLHHHLHLHL        \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
```

Comment: It's your 9th question: Please provide a complete code example as describes here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111423 and https://texample.net/tikz/examples/more-tikz-timing-examples/.